# PHP: session variable is getting overwritten

Tags: php, yii, session-variables

I'm creating a ecommerce application and by using that application user can create their own ecommerce store like bigcommerce. So I'm using `$_SESSION['store_id']` to each store and using that variable throughout the application to control the store.

Now, the problem is user cannot access multiple store on a single browser, because the `$_SESSION['store_id']` is getting overwritten.
I know PHP session variable is just like any other array so if the key is same then it will overwrite the value of the corresponding key. But, how I can solve this issue? 
Should I create dynamic PHP session variable?

For your information, my application is almost finished using Yii framework, so its pretty difficult to hard-code.

Comment: how about `array` for this key? And then `if(!in_array($value, $_SESSION['store_id'])){ $_SESSION['store_id'][] = $value; }` or something like that.

Comment: @CORRUPT If I use the array to that key, I've to hard-code whole app.

Comment: i think is a bad practive to store current visited store in session (you have encounted the main issue : session data is erased when use visit another store). I think each store must have a unique URL slug or id (http://domain.com/my-supa-store-01/  or http://domain.com/store/12) to identify them.

Answer (score 1):

You could try storing stores by key

```
$_SESSION['stores'] = array(
   'store_id' => 'session data'
);
```

Comment: @CORRUPT beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

You can use list of store in session in following way

```
         session_start()
          if( ! isset( $_SESSION['list_of_store']))
               {
             $_SESSION['list_of_store']=array('0'=>$store_id)
               }
          else
            {
             $stores=$_SESSION['list_of_store'];
             $stores[]=$store_id;
            $_SESSION['list_of_store']=$stores;

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing some sort of "keychain"-button, that includes all the stores that particular person is an admin of.
Should one want to administer another store, he/she could click on the keychain button and choose which store to adminster.